# I've got a qr code output with an exact value but I don't know how to store the generated image. How can I store a qr-code image?

Tags: php

In the code I have a value string as a test and I am getting an output once I scan qr-code. I would like to store that qr-code image in a folder.

```
include 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
$value = "test";
if($count > 0)
{                 
     QRcode::png('code data text', 'filename.png'); // creates file 
     $result = QRcode::png($values); // creates code image and outputs it 
                                                directly into browser
}
```

Comment: You're already storing a png under `filename.png` in this code. Which bit isn't working?

Comment: [`QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);`](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=005)

Comment: qr-code is generated and displayed in web page , is there a way to that image in folder

Comment: Your code is already commented with what each line does... just delete the bit that you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options,

1. Just store the `coded data text` in a file or database
2. Store the qrcode binary in a database (`QRcode::text($codeContents)`)
3. Store the qrcode to a file like @DarkBee said `QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);`

Good luck!